# Set lxml as default BeautifulSoup parser

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

I'm working on a web scraping project and have ran into problems with speed. To try to fix it, I want to use lxml instead of html.parser as BeautifulSoup's parser. I've been able to do this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

but I don't want to have to repeatedly type `'lxml'` every time I call BeautifulSoup. Is there a way I can set which parser to use once at the beginning of my program?

Comment: `lxml` *is* the default in `bs4`, assuming you have `lxml` installed.  So unless you happen to be working with BeautifulSoup3...

Comment: I am using bs4, but I didn't know how to check which parser I was currently using. Thank you!

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511544 containing other details.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [Specifying the parser to use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) documentation page:

> The first argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor is a string or an
>   open filehandle–the markup you want parsed. The second argument is how
>   you’d like the markup parsed.
>
> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

In other words, just installing `lxml` in the same python environment makes it a default parser.

Though note, that explicitly stating a parser is considered a best-practice approach. There are [differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) that can result into subtle errors which would be difficult to debug if you are letting `BeautifulSoup` choose the best parser by itself. You would also have to remember that you need to have `lxml` installed. And, if you would not have it installed, you would not even notice it - `BeautifulSoup` would just get the next available parser without throwing any errors.

If you still don't want to specify the parser explicitly, at least make a note for future yourself or others who would use the code you've written in the project's README/documentation, and list `lxml` in your project requirements alongside with `beautifulsoup4`.

Besides: ["Explicit is better than implicit."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Note, with bs4 version 4.5.1, when specifuing 'lxml' parser and not having it installed bs4 **does** error out:
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Answer (score 12):

Obviously take a look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791286/1317713) first. It is pretty good, and as for this technicality:

> but I don't want to have to repeatedly type 'lxml' every time I call
>   BeautifulSoup. Is there a way I can set which parser to use once at
>   the beginning of my program?

If I understood your question correctly, I can think of two approaches that will save you some keystrokes: - Define a wrapper function, or - Create a partial function.

```
# V1 - define a wrapper function - most straight-forward.
import bs4

def bs_parse(html):
    return bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
# ...
html = ...
bs_parse(html)
```

Or if you feel like showing off ...

```
import bs4
from functools import partial
bs_parse = partial(bs4.BeautifulSoup, features='lxml')
# ...
html = ...
bs_parse(html)
```

Comment: Can you add explanation to how `partial` works? Are there any advantages to using it over a wrapper function?

Comment: @r3robertson There is good documentation for partial functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

It looks to me like partial is both slower and more complicated under the hood as compared to a wrapper, but once it has been implemented, it is rather easy to use. Partial functions are clean for a lack of a better word from mathematical point of view. Other languages have this and it is considered a good use of functional programming by some, but you do pay a price in terms of speed and an extra import. I still use partial functions because they are fun.

Comment: @r3robertson By the way, partial functions do not have to create extra overhead when using certain compiled languages that make performance a priority, but Python is not one of those languages. C++ is however https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/cpp17_curry.html