# How to get rid of BeautifulSoup user warning?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After I installed BeautifulSoup, whenever I run my Python in from the command line, this warning comes out:

```
D:\Application\python\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3.4.egg\bs4\__init__.py:166:
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best 
available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a
problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different
virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")
```

I have no idea why it comes out and how to solve it.

Comment: The message is telling you exactly what to do: `BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")`. Did you do that and see what your output is? BeautifulSoup is trying to make your life easier. Listen to the Soup. :)

Comment: Change your code such like `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The solution to your problem is clearly stated in the error message. Code like the below does not specify an XML/HTML/etc. parser.

```
BeautifulSoup( ... )
```

In order to fix the error, you'll need to specify which parser you'd like to use, like so:

```
BeautifulSoup( ..., "html.parser" )
```

You can also install a 3rd party parser if you'd like.

Comment: See Beautiful Soup's [installing a parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) docs for the advantages/disadvantages of some common parsers (html.parser, lxml, html5lib)

Answer (score 23):

Documentation recommends that you install and use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for speed.

```
BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

> If you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version
>   of Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install lxml
>   or html5lib–Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in
>   older versions.

**Installing LXML parser**

- On Ubuntu (debian)

  ```
  apt-get install python-lxml
  ```
- Fedora (RHEL based)

  ```
  dnf install python-lxml
  ```
- Using PIP

  ```
  pip install lxml
  ```

Comment: Or `apt-get install python3-lxml`.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, the previous posts did not answer the question.

Yes, as everyone said, you can remove the warning by specifying the parser.
And as pointed by the documentation, it is a best-practice for performances <sup>[1](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)</sup> and for consistency <sup>[2](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)</sup>.

But in some cases, you want to silence the warning... Hence this post.

- since BeautifulSoup 4 [rev 460](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/revision/460), the warning message does not appear in interactive ([REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)) mode
- there are more generalist answers at: [How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277) to control Python warnings (TL;DL: [`PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) or [`-Wignore`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w))
- suppressing the warning explicitly (bs4 ≥ [rev 569](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/revision/569)) by adding to your code:

  ```py
  import warnings
  from bs4 import GuessedAtParserWarning
  warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=GuessedAtParserWarning)
  ```
- cheating by letting bs4 think you provided the parser, i.e.:

  ```py
  bs4.BeautifulSoup(
    your_markup,
    builder=bs4.builder_registry.lookup(*bs4.BeautifulSoup.DEFAULT_BUILDER_FEATURES)
  )
  ```

Comment: To quote PEP-20, point 2: "Explicit is better than implicit". Don't hide warnings when the proper fix is less code. Adding "html5lib" or "html.parser" is trivial in an IDE or code editor, and almost-trivial on the command line. Just fix the problem, don't hide the symptom.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes a library spams the warning, and filtering it is the solution

Comment: And sometimes you're actually parsing XHTML which is, after all, an XML document. Thus specifying `lxml` is correct and you still get the warning.

Answer (score 6):

For HTML parser, you need to install html5lib, run:

```
pip install html5lib
```

then add html5lib in the BeautifulSoup method:

```
htmlDoc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req1.text, 'html5lib')
print(htmlDoc)
```