# Unknown errors in webcrawler-dictionary (Python, modules: beautifulsoup4, operator, requests)

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and I have developed a program that is is meant to crawl a website (that sells things) and print out the frequency of different words in the titles of the different items on sale.

There are three functions in my program:
1) A function that takes the text of the website and refines it to make a string 
2) A function that takes that string and cleans it up, getting rid of things like brackets, commas, asterisks etc.
3) A function that then takes this string and sorts the words by how many times they are written on the website

I had an error in this program with my BeautifulSoup4 module, this other post helped me get rid of it: [How to get rid of BeautifulSoup user warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511544/how-to-get-rid-of-beautifulsoup-user-warning) 
Although this made two more errors in my program:
1) An error with the link I put into the first function

```
File "/Users/lowryj1/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Jaer.py", line 39, in <module>
start('https://hongkong.asiaxpat.com/classifieds/glassware/')
```

And this is the code that is wrong (The link is the website I'm crawling):

```
start('https://hongkong.asiaxpat.com/classifieds/glassware/')
```

2) This in an error with my line of code where I try to split the string in the first function and make all of the characters lowercase, this just makes this error:

```
File "/Users/lowryj1/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Jaer.py", line 11, in start
words = content.lower().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

And this is the code that is wrong:

```
words = content.lower().split()
```

This is the area I have the error (url is where my website url comes in):

```
def start(url):
word_list = []
source_code = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html5lib")
for post_text in soup.findAll('a', {'target': '_blank'}):
    content = post_text.string
    **words = content.lower().split()**
```

I have tried my best to solve these problems, most solutions I've tried only make the issues worse. Please help me solve these errors, as I was unable to find adequate solutions to this problem via research.

Comment: I need your code snippets to help. Please, add. Don't too much code, but all the things related to your problem, probably shortened details somewhere.

Comment: Tip: You can edit your question

Comment: it looks like `content = post_text.string` is blank so that when you try to call `.lower()` on it in the next line `words = content.lower().split()` its throwing the error. Can you check if there is content in `post_text.string`?

Comment: @Craicerjack When you say check, does printing out post_text.string work with checking it? If so, there is content in post_text.string.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I see slightly different syntax for `find_all` in the [docs for bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

But assuming your syntax also correct, it fails with issue that some of the  found `post_text`s has no textual content (i.e. `.string`) and returns `None`. You need check your anchors for it, probably it is an error in the sources.

But if you want just avoid the issue - use

```
if post_text.string is not None:
    content = post_text.string
    words = content.lower().split()
```

Comment: That does seem to solve the issue, but three other problems popped up when I did that that I do not know how to solve.

Comment: You're still specified too little data about other problems. Also, unfortunately, I think that you're actually asking to write the code for your three tasks instead of you. This isn't an SO style. So, try to ask about exact problems. For example: I have the code, but it gives me an error, or I want to achieve some goal and tried my code, but it doesn't work, or is there a method in some library to achieve my goal. Try it! :-)